# Executing query via nested inner class query handler

Tags: c#

**Background**

I often see blogs/articles split out the implementation of the `Query` and `QueryHandler` classes. I had briefly asked a question on Stack Overflow about whether or not a self-executing `Query` class would be a violation of SOLID design principals (I deleted the question as it was feeling like the wrong place to ask for feedback). My opinion was that a `Query` class represents a single operation within a system, and that the separation of parameters/execution was unnecessary in most cases...

I understand that in some cases there may be legitimate reasons for doing so (i.e., using `Query` object *AS* your view model, not to my taste). One comment on the original question suggested the inability to cleanly apply decorators to a merged `Query` class in order to enhance query execution and although I had considered the suggestions at the time to be the responsibility of a `QueryProcessor`, it got me thinking: as modification of one will more often than not result in modification of the other. Perhaps nesting the handler class would be a *happy middle ground* as shown in the implementation below.

**Implementation**

```
/// <summary>
/// Query definition used to retrieve a specific user by their username.
/// </summary>
public sealed class GetUserByUsernameQuery : Query<User>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The unique user username to locate.
    /// </summary>
    public Username Username { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="GetUserByUsernameQuery"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username">The unique user username to locate.</param>
    public GetUserByUsernameQuery(Username username)
    {
        if (username == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(username));

        Username = username;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles processing of a <see cref="GetUserByUsernameQuery "/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    internal sealed class Handler : SqlQueryHandler<GetUserByUsernameQuery, User>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the specified <paramref name="query"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="query">The query instance to process.</param>
        protected override IEnumerable<User> Execute(GetUserByUsernameQuery query)
        {
            using (var connection = OpenConnection())
                return connection.Query<User>("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[GetUserByUsername](@username);", query);
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** No comments regarding `SELECT *`. The Inline Table Function explicitly selects only the required columns for the result set and I see no reason to define the columns again in the code.

---

I know some people consider inner classes to be *evil*, however in this case my thinking is that an inner class provides a nice balance between a self-executing Query and full separation between the `Query`/`QueryHandler` classes (i.e., easy to edit within a single file).

My rational:

- There will only ever be a single handler class per query.
- The handler will often have to be modified if the query class were to change.
- Allows for decorators etc to be applied to the `QueryHandler` if required.
- The `QueryHandler` class really cannot exist without the `Query` class.

Are there any major downsides to going down this path? Any other suggestions on how to achieve balance between the two ends of the spectrum? I would also be interested in feedback on using inline table functions for Dapper queries. I typically place my SQL in embedded resource files or a resource file, but I thought this might be better option?

NOTE: My use case does not require that the `Query`/`QueryHandler` ever need to live in different assemblies; thus dependencies are not a concern. And worst case, I could easily refactor if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that we should be able to execute different query handlers given the same query parameters – for testing purposes. Simple data transfer object (query) being passed to the repository interface allows us to do it in a well-known and understandable way.

The same time the following works well for me (SSAS MDX queries)…

To define MDX I use a partial class in multiple files (example):

```
// SalesSummary.cs
public static partial class MdxQueries
{
    public static IEnumerable<TradeSummary> SalesSummary(DateTime day, string department) =>
        new MdxQuery($@"MDX SCRIPT WITH PARAMETER={day} AND PARAMETER={department}")
            .Select(r => new TradeSummary
            {
                Product = r["Product"],
                Total = r["Total"]
            });
}

// PurchaseSummary.cs
public static partial class MdxQueries
{
    public static IEnumerable<TradeSummary> PurchaseSummary(DateTime day, string department) =>
        new MdxQuery($@"MDX SCRIPT WITH PARAMETER={day} AND PARAMETER={department}")
            .Select(r => new TradeSummary
            {
                Product = r["Product"],
                Total = r["Total"]
            });
}
```

Where library classes are:

```
public class MdxQuery : IEnumerable<MdxRow>
{
    static string ConnectionString => ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SSAS"]
        .ConnectionString;

    public MdxQuery(string mdx)
        : this(mdx, ConnectionString)
    {
    }

    public MdxQuery(string mdx, string connectionString)
    {
        _mdx = mdx;
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    readonly string _mdx;
    readonly string _connectionString;

    public IEnumerator<MdxRow> GetEnumerator()
    {
        using (var connection = new AdomdConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = _mdx;
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
                yield return new MdxRow(reader);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    public static implicit operator MdxQuery(string mdx) =>
        new MdxQuery(mdx);
}
```

Where:

```
public struct MdxRow
{
    internal MdxRow(AdomdDataReader reader)
    {
        Values = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
            .ToDictionary(i => reader.GetName(i), i => new MdxValue(reader[i]));

        ValuesByIndex = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
            .ToDictionary(i => i, i => new MdxValue(reader[i]));
    }

    public MdxValue this[string column] => Values[$"[Measures].[{column}]"];
    public MdxValue this[int column] => ValuesByIndex[column];
    Dictionary<string, MdxValue> Values { get; }
    Dictionary<int, MdxValue> ValuesByIndex { get; }
}
```

Where:

```
public struct MdxValue
{
    public MdxValue(object value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    object Value { get; }

    public static implicit operator string(MdxValue value) =>
        Convert.ToString(value.Value);

    public static implicit operator int(MdxValue value) =>
        Convert.ToInt32(value.Value ?? 0);

    public static implicit operator double(MdxValue value) =>
        Convert.ToDouble(value.Value ?? 0);

    public static implicit operator int? (MdxValue value) =>
        value.IsNull ? (int?)null : (int)value;

    public static implicit operator double? (MdxValue value) =>
        value.IsNull ? (double?)null : (double)value;

    public static implicit operator DateTime(MdxValue value) =>
        DateTime.Parse((string)value ?? DateTime.MinValue.ToString());

    public static implicit operator DateTime? (MdxValue value) =>
        value.IsNull ? (DateTime?)null : (DateTime)value;

    public bool IsNull => Value == null;
}
```

All this stuff is used to implement repositories, which depend on DTO.

Comment: I would not plan to use a separate `QueryHandler` for testing, as I could easily configure the backing store to be an in-memory database or mock out the underlying connection if preferred (i.e., no need for a fake implementation). As such, I stand by my single `QueryHandler` statement... that being said, the class shown above does not handle DI, so that did need to be addressed. I opted to split out the class and conform to the masses; mostly because .NET Core projects auto nest files and that makes the artificial separation tolerable). Leaving open for now pending additional feedback.